# Extension option Missing in SPFX

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions, share

i am trying creating extension but not [image]getting extension option only getting webpart

Comment: i got it it should be SharePoint 2019 onwards, including SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kumar said, you need to choose 2019 Onward

BUT also notice that they dropped support for these options since 1.13.x
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/yeoman-generator-for-spfx-intro#retired-generator-prompts

on the other hand, PnP/generator can help you with that also
https://pnp.github.io/generator-spfx/#command-line-options
including for on-prems

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a SharePoint Extension choose any one of the below options for the question, Which baseline packages do you want to target for your component(s)?:

SharePoint Online only (latest)
SharePoint 2019 onwards, including SharePoint Online